# List All Routes in a Roda app

Tags: ruby, rake, roda

In Rails I view all the routes I have defined via:

`rake routes`

Is there a built in way to do this in a Roda app?

If not, is there a common pattern Roda developers use to quickly view all the routes (maybe a Rake task of some sorts?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatically is not possible. `roda` routes are evaluated dynamically when a request comes in, so they are not loaded before and stored in a data structure available somewhere.

As the [documentation](http://roda.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html) says:

> The route block is called whenever a new request comes in. It is yielded an instance of a subclass of Rack::Request with some additional methods for matching routes.

A simple solution, which needs a minimal effort, is to use the [`roda-route_list`](https://github.com/jeremyevans/roda-route_list#basic-usage) plugin, but it needs explanatory comment on the top of each route in your `app.rb` file, like this:

```
# route: /path/to/foo
# route: GET /path/to/foo
# ...
```

(check the [documentation](https://github.com/jeremyevans/roda-route_list#basic-usage) for other possibilities)

Then you have to create a json file containing the routes metadata, you can do this launching a script shipped with `roda-route_list` plugin

```
roda-parse_routes -f routes.json app.rb
```

It creates the file `routes.json` in the root of your app and finally you can list the routes with:

```
route_list # => [{:path=>'/path/to/foo', :methods=>['GET', 'POST']}]
# (it is an Array of route metadata hashes)
```

You could create also a simple rake task to list all routes, something like this:

```
# Rakefile
require 'roda'

namespace :routes do
  task :list do |task|
    class App < Roda
      plugin :route_list
      puts route_list
    end
  end
end
```

maybe there is a more elegant solution than this snippet, but it works :)

Hope it helps!